# The simple transition of matrix but what went wrong?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    int A[3][2] = {0} ;

    printf("A = \n");   
    for(int x = 0 ; x < 3 ; x++){
        for (int y = 0 ; y < 2 ; y ++){
            A[x][y] = (x+1)*1 + (x*1+3)*y ; 
            printf("A[%d][%d] = %d ", x , y ,A[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
    printf("\nAT = \n");    
    for (int p = 0 ; p < 2 ; p++){
        for (int q = 0 ; q < 3 ; q++){
            A[p][q] = A[q][p];
            printf("A[%d][%d] = %d ", p ,q , A[p][q]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Why does AT[1][0] = 2 not 4?

I have tested it for an hour for this simple question, but I have no idea.

Comment: In the expression `A[p][q] = A[q][p]`, what do you think happens when `q` is `2` (and out of bounds for the nested array)?

Answer (score 2):

If you transpose a non-square matrix then the dimensions of the resulting matrix will also be transposed. Not only that, if you were going to transpose in-place you would need to *swap* pairs of elements, otherwise you would be overwriting some of the elements before they had been transposed.

So, to solve both these problems you should probably just use a second matrix with the correct dimensions for the transposed result, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int A[3][2] = {0};
    int AT[2][3] = {0};  // <<<

    printf("A = \n");   
    for(int x = 0 ; x < 3 ; x++){
        for (int y = 0 ; y < 2 ; y ++){
            A[x][y] = (x+1)*1 + (x*1+3)*y ; 
            printf("A[%d][%d] = %d ", x, y, A[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
    printf("\nAT = \n");    
    for (int p = 0 ; p < 2 ; p++){
        for (int q = 0 ; q < 3 ; q++){
            AT[p][q] = A[q][p]; // <<<
            printf("A[%d][%d] = %d ", p, q, AT[p][q]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8cc3eafc1930cd7)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the array out of bounds when the condition came,

```
 A[0][2]=A[2][0]; // <--
```

Here You can access only until first location. So as like `Paul R` says Use the
separate array when you transpose the array.

For example consider your array is declared in memory like this.

```
Memory Address     125    126     127     128     129     130
                    ^      ^       ^       ^       ^       ^
                    |      |       |       |       |       |
Array accessing  [0][0]  [0][1]  [1][0]  [1][1]  [2][0]  [2][1]
```

what will happen when you are accessing the `[0][2]`. It will go to the `[1][0]`.